# A Probability Game of Bridge Problem and Its Puzzling Correct Answer

Tags: probability, card-games

In my effort to work on my probability and combinatorics skills before the semester starts, I have come across this problem:

What is the probability that a bridge hand will contain 13 cards of the same suit?

In my opinion, the answer should be 4/(52C13), i.e. 6.3*10^(-12), which is consistent with [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176628/13-card-bridge-hand-is-drawn-from-a-deck-of-52-cards) and many others of the kind but apparently, the correct answer is:
5.25*10^(-13)

What am I doing wrong? I am probably confused because, well, frankly speaking, my understanding of the game of bridge is limited to everything I learned about it from probability problems.

Answer (score 1):

Under the usual assumptions, the probability that the South hand has $13$ cards of the same suit is indeed $\frac{4}{\binom{52}{13}}$.

For there are $\binom{52}{13}$ equally likely ways to choose the South hand, and $4$ of them are "favourable."

The probability is about $6.3\times 10^{-12}$. (I have relied on software to compute $\binom{52}{13}$.)

We could interpret the problem differently, and ask for the probability that at least one of the four hands consists of cards of the same suit. But this probability is clearly *bigger* than the probability that South's cards are all of the same suit. The calculation for the probability is interesting, for multiplying our answer by $4$ overcounts the situations in which more than one hand is one-suited. So we need to use Inclusion/Exclusion.

I cannot think of a variant of the problem that produces a probability of size about $5.25\times 10^{-13}$.